# How to set amount field of iframe in payment gateway

Tags: javascript, php

Because we are not PCI compliant, the payment gateway providers gave us `<iframe>` to make payments. The issue is I cannot set the amount field inside the iframe with my cart total(19.00).

check out page:

[image: check out page]

payment page:

[image: payment page]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   

   $('#myiframe').load(function(){

        var iframe = $('#myiframe').contents();               

        iframe.find("#amount").val(<?php echo total; ?>);
        iframe.find("#firstname").attr('readonly','readonly');
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="myiframe" src="paymentgateway.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code does not work as negete.net/sys/checkout.php is in one domain and payment form in another domain. Reason is problem with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

I tried to solve this, but nothing worked. If anyone has encountered issues like this, your help is much appreciated. Given below are some links which I found related to CORS.

Comment: Although its possible, best practice is to read up on your payment gateway provider's api document to know how to pass values to it. If you insist on doing otherwise, you can try searching for "edit iframe dom".

Comment: I tried to use window.postmessage(). But i don't have control inside the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a way to tackle the above issue. Actually it is in payment gateway issuer's documentation which I missed. The solution is you can pass the amount as an query string in iframe url .

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="paymentgateway.com?amount=50">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: seems like i also miss this part, where did you find in dcumentation? i am trying to put payment info in iframe but cant figure out how to code it inside samplegateway.php